# Remove Past Dates - Jquery Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a booking system for a client, I managed to disable sundays & mondays (days she is not open) I'm trying to tidy it up a bit and block out days that have already past.

I have the function written to block out sundays & mondays but i'm trying to integrate the block past dates into it as well. I tried adding it into the function I have but I can't seem to get it to work. (I am aware that the first 2 lines are commented out) If I leave both of them in, it only blocks out the prior dates but doesn't block out Sun & Mon

```
<script>
 // set minDate to 0 for today's date
    //  $('#datepicker').datepicker({ minDate: 0 });
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      // 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday
      return [date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 1 ? false : true];
    }
  });
});
 </script>
```

I would like to get the block prior dates & block sun & mon working on this in one function is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `minDate`

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  minDate: '0d',
  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    // 0 - Sunday, 1 - Monday
    return [date.getDay() == 0 || date.getDay() == 1 ? false : true];
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input id="datepicker"/>
```